# Fluentvalidation - tie validation to specific process best practice

Tags: c#, validation, c#-4.0, moq, fluentvalidation

what would be the best practice for tying validation rules to specific process using http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/

Currently I'm using "Rule Sets" feature to group rules to different processes:

```
 public class ObjAValidation: AbstractValidator<A>
    {
        public ObjAValidation()
        {
            RuleSet("ProcessA", () =>
            {
                RuleFor(x => ...);
                RuleFor(x => ...);
            }); 
           RuleSet("ProcessB", () =>
            {
                RuleFor(x => ...);
                RuleFor(x => ...);
            }); 
        }
    }
```

And then validate using:

```
var a = new A(){...};
IValidator<A> validator = new ObjAValidation();
var result = validator.Validate(a, ruleSet: "ProcessA");
```

I have two problems with this approach:

1. I don't like to use strings as process names. I would like to use a
   more strongly typed approach. For example to be able to use marker
   interfaces or attributes.
2. In my Unit tests I can't setup the Validate method of IValidator
   because you can't use optional arguments with Moq.

```
Mock<IValidator<A>> _mockValidator = new Mock<IValidator<A>>();
_mockValidator.Setup(x => x.Validate(new A(), ruleSet: "ProcessA"));
```

Second line generates a run time error: **An expression tree may not contain a named argument specification.** And if you want to pass the ruleSet argument without a named argument to Validate method you have to provide a "IValidatorSelector selector" object. But this interface is not documented.

Comment: ​have you consider  EntLib Validation Application Block? It also support ruleSets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What prevents you to create a helper class where you can use variables, data structures, anything you like to prevent the usage of hard-coded string parameters? Also, don't forget the possibility of using enums.

What prevents you from creating a class which implements IValidator where you can also implement custom functionality needed by you?

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same issue and found out the reason why you can not mock this method via Moq etc `validator.Validate(a, ruleSet: "ProcessA");` is because it is an extension method and Moq can't mock static methods.

Someone raised the same issue here in the FluentValidation issues: https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation/issues/191

The simple solution is not to use the extension method rather use the instant method `IValidator.validate(context)`. All you need to do is to build the context. Check out the source code from here: https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation/blob/master/src/FluentValidation/DefaultValidatorExtensions.cs#L819

```
if(ruleSet != null) {
                var ruleSetNames = ruleSet.Split(',', ';').Select(x => x.Trim());
                selector = ValidatorOptions.ValidatorSelectors.RulesetValidatorSelectorFactory(ruleSetNames.ToArray());
            } 

            var context = new ValidationContext<T>(instance, new PropertyChain(), selector);
            return validator.Validate(context);
```